# Как подключить к одной Arduino Uno 8 серво моторчиков?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Cначала подумал, что это не проблема, но понял, что ЦИФРОВЫХ портов в Arduino Uno меньше 8. Как можно подключить все 8 серво моторчиков не покупая новую плату? (Каждый из них должен управляться отдельно)

Comment: Ну, много вариантов: от [расширителей GPIO портов](https://amperka.ru/product/troyka-gpio-expander) и всяческих [серво шилдов](https://amperka.ru/product/arduino-multiservo-shield) до просто Arduion Mega (может оказаться проще и дешевле купить китайскую мегу вместо всяких расширителей).

Comment: Проблема в том что я изначально сделал проект где все место занято, и Arduino Mega или же всякие расширители туда могут не влезть

Comment: Расширитель пинов, на который я ссылку дал, мало места занимает, примерно как 1/6 платы ардуино. Гребенку можно выпаять, если по высоте мешает, подпаяться напрямую к плате.

Comment: http://easyelectronics.ru/upravlenie-mnozhestvom-servomashinok.html

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях я использую либо шину [I2C](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10216.pdf) как-раз для таких ситуаций или же можно использовать специальный [расширитель портов](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32469378576.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.28187af5UoIRo9&algo_pvid=null&algo_expid=null&btsid=0b8b15d416263231088102892e9d97&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) он стоит подешевле чем mega. Но я бы использовал I2C. И насчет цифровых портов то их двенадцать штук только 0 и 1 (TLL) а остальные цифровые просто выводы 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 и 11 способны формировать широтно-импульсную модуляцию (ШИМ) с помощью функции analogWrite().